# maximum volume?

Tags: calculus

[image: gutter]

I know I have to derive the formula for the volume $V=A_{base}*h$, with $h=600cm$, set it equal to zero and the result would be the maximum, but I don't know what parameters to take to get the area of ​​the triangle.
I hope you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram, we can see that $(x/2)^2 + y^2 = 0.5^2$ by the Pythagorean theorem on the triangle face. From your diagram, we can see that the volume is equal to $\frac{xy}2$ for the face area times $6$ for the height, so we get $V=3xy$, which is the quantity we want to maximize. Use this equation $(x/2)^2 + y^2 = 0.5^2$ and solve for $y$. We get $ y = \sqrt{0.25-x^2/4}$. Substitute this into the volume equation to get $V=3x\sqrt{0.25-x^2/4}$. Find $V'$ and set it to $0$, and find the $x$ that makes $V' = 0$. Use $x$ to then find $y$. I hope this helps.